# What's wrong with my react unit testing? Every time I tried to test if removeCoupon works, its failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I was trying to create a unit test for my react Component named OrderTotal. So test for rendering its working fine. But when I wrote one for removeCoupon I can't make it work.
**Just a note removeCoupon is a method that dispatch an action (deleteCouponCode) So behind that action there is an API where I request a delete request and it deals with redux state.

**
Below is my main component.

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
//@ts-ignore
import { useJumboTheme } from "@jumbo/hooks";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "app/redux/reducers/hooks";
//@ts-ignore
import { ReactComponent as MinusIcon } from "../../../../../images/icons/minus_icon.svg";
import { deleteCouponCode, getOrder } from "app/redux/actions/subscriptions";
import { SET_ORDER, SET_PAYMENT } from "app/utils/constants/createSubscription";

interface Props {
  bgColor?: string;
}

const OrderTotal = ({ bgColor }: Props) => {
  const { theme } = useJumboTheme();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { order, payment } = useAppSelector(
    ({ createSubscription }) => createSubscription
  );
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    (title: string, amount: any, isTotal?: boolean) => {
      const currency = order?.currency?.localizedCode || order?.currency?.code;
      let textStyle;

      if (isTotal) {
        textStyle = { fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 500 };
      } else {
        textStyle = { fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 400 };
      }

      return (
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            alignItems: "center",
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontWeight: 400,
          }}
          mb={1}
        >
          <Typography sx={textStyle}>{title}</Typography>
          <Typography sx={textStyle}>
            {amount} {currency}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      );
    },
    [order?.currency?.localizedCode, order?.currency?.code]
  );

  const getUpdateOrder = useCallback(
    (data: any) => {
      dispatch({ type: SET_ORDER, payload: data });
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  const removeCouponCallback = useCallback(
    (data: any) => {
      if (data) {
        // Delete the "coupon" and "couponData" properties
        const { coupon, couponData, ...paymentWithoutCoupon } = payment;

        dispatch({
          type: SET_PAYMENT,
          payload: { ...paymentWithoutCoupon },
        });

        dispatch(getOrder(data.orderId, getUpdateOrder));
      }
    },
    [dispatch, payment, getUpdateOrder]
  );

  const removeCoupon = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(deleteCouponCode(order?.orderId, removeCouponCallback));
  }, [dispatch, order?.orderId, removeCouponCallback]);

  const renderDiscountCode = useCallback(() => {
    if (payment?.coupon) {
      return (
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontWeight: 400,
          }}
          mb={1}
        >
          <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 400 }}>
            {t("pages.subscription.create.activeCoupon", {
              code: payment?.coupon,
            })}
          </Typography>
          <IconButton
            disableRipple={true}
            onClick={removeCoupon}
            data-testid="remove-coupon-button"
          >
            <MinusIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }, [payment?.coupon, removeCoupon, t]);

  return (
    <Box
      data-testid="order-total-component"
      sx={{
        borderRadius: 2,
        p: 2,
        backgroundColor: bgColor
          ? bgColor
          : theme.components.subscription.paymentBg,
      }}
    >
      <Typography gutterBottom sx={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 500 }}>
        {t("pages.subscription.create.summary")}
      </Typography>
      {renderItem(t("pages.subscription.create.subTotal"), order?.subTotal)}
      {renderItem(
        t("pages.subscription.create.discountedAmount"),
        `- ${order?.discountedAmount}`
      )}
      {renderDiscountCode()}
      {renderItem(t("pages.subscription.create.tax"), order?.vat)}
      {renderItem(t("pages.subscription.create.total"), order?.total, true)}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default React.memo(OrderTotal);
```

I tried to write the test for it the reference is posted below.

So at the last part of it, is my test for removeCoupon method but on the last expect. The element that supposed to be gone is still there.

So if you could help me understand, and fix this that would be great.

**Just a note removeCoupon is a method that dispatch an action (deleteCouponCode) So behind that action there is an API where I request a delete request and it deals with redux state.
**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import OrderTotal from "../OrderTotal";
import TestParentWrapper from "app/common/TestParentWrapper";
import i18n from "app/config/i18n";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import * as subscriptionAPI from "app/services/subscriptions";

// mock any API requests used on this component
jest.mock("app/services/subscriptions");

describe("OrderTotal", () => {
  const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

  const order = {
    orderId: 1019,
    subTotal: 76.9,
    discountedAmount: 21,
    vat: 5,
    total: 55.9,
    currency: {
      localizedCode: "USD",
      code: "USD",
    },
  };
  const payment = {
    coupon: "TESTCoupon",
    couponData: {},
  };

  it("renders OrderTotal", () => {
    const initialState = {
      createSubscription: {
        order,
      },
    };

    render(
      <TestParentWrapper>
        <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
          <OrderTotal />
        </Provider>
      </TestParentWrapper>
    );

    const orderTotalComponent = screen.getByTestId("order-total-component");
    expect(orderTotalComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("renders items with amount and currency", () => {
    const initialState = {
      createSubscription: {
        order,
      },
    };

    render(
      <TestParentWrapper>
        <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
          <OrderTotal />
        </Provider>
      </TestParentWrapper>
    );

    const currencyCode = initialState.createSubscription.order.currency.code;

    const subTotalText = `${initialState.createSubscription.order.subTotal} ${currencyCode}`;
    const subTotalElement = screen.getByText(subTotalText);
    expect(subTotalElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("renders discountCode if available", () => {
    const initialState = {
      createSubscription: {
        order,
        payment,
      },
    };

    render(
      <TestParentWrapper>
        <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
          <OrderTotal />
        </Provider>
      </TestParentWrapper>
    );

    const text = `${i18n.t("pages.subscription.create.activeCoupon", {
      code: initialState.createSubscription.payment?.coupon,
    })}`;
    const textElement = screen.getByText(text);
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("does not render discountCode if not available", () => {
    const initialState = {
      createSubscription: {
        order,
        payment: { coupon: null }, // Assuming null indicates no coupon available
      },
    };

    render(
      <TestParentWrapper>
        <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
          <OrderTotal />
        </Provider>
      </TestParentWrapper>
    );

    const text = `${i18n.t("pages.subscription.create.activeCoupon", {
      code: null, // Assuming null is used to display empty code
    })}`;
    const textElement = screen.queryByText(text); // Use queryByText instead of getByText
    expect(textElement).toBeNull(); // Assert that the textElement is null (not found)
  });

  // TODO: Test the methods

  it("should call removeCoupon when remove-coupon-button is clicked", async () => {
    const initialState = {
      createSubscription: {
        order,
        payment,
      },
    };

    render(
      <TestParentWrapper>
        <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
          <OrderTotal />
        </Provider>
      </TestParentWrapper>
    );

    // applied coupon showed
    const text = `${i18n.t("pages.subscription.create.activeCoupon", {
      code: initialState.createSubscription.payment?.coupon,
    })}`;
    const textElement = screen.getByText(text);
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();

    const removeCouponButton = screen.getByTestId("remove-coupon-button");
    fireEvent.click(removeCouponButton);

    const textUpdatedElement = screen.getByText(text);

    expect(textUpdatedElement).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).